# What subjects properly belong in operations research as their "owning" discipline?

Tags: optimization, soft-question, linear-programming, operations-research

**Warning: This is a soft question, hence I would make it a wiki-community post if I could.**

Operations Research involves a broad swath of disciplines, ranging from probability and statistics/stochastic processes, to computer programming, to vector algebra and vector calculus. However, none of these are unique to OR. However, there is *something* to OR as a distinct field of research.

I've come up with a list of subjects that seem to be "owned" by OR (although used by others):

1. Mathematical Programming (Linear, Nonlinear, Multicriteria, Dynamic, etc)
2. Decision Analysis
3. Discrete-event simulation
4. Post-optimality analysis

Also, here are some fields that are used *by* OR, but are not properly part of OR as a distinct subject would include:

1. Statistics
2. Probability theory and stochastic processes
3. Numerical optimization and numerical methods in general
4. Database programming
5. Data mining/text mining
6. Predictive modelling
7. Monte Carlo simulation
8. Linear algebra and advanced calculus

Anyway, that's my list, but I was hoping others  may care to add their thoughts and opinions.